# How to Return a structure

Tags: c++, function, structure

How Can I return all the structures when i choose 7.Logout after i insert a record from the Admin menu, and if i return to the admin menu, i'll see the record again.

For Example

User:Admin
Pass:Admin

then i choose 2.Insert Product after that Ill go choose 1.display , after that i 7.log out. now i want to login again as Admin but i want to see all the data again.please help this is our thesis project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct product{

    string pname,pid;
    int qnty;
    double price;

    product *ptr;
};

//Function Declaration
void Menu(string username);
void InsertProduct();
void DeleteProduct();
void DisplayProduct();
void SearchProduct();
void PurchaseProduct();
//

product *head;

int main() //Account Login
{
    int pw=0,n;
    char pwc=' ';
    string username,password;

    cout<<"\n ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t      LICA'S GROCERY STORE"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"\t\t\t    Username: ";
    getline(cin, username);

    cout<<"\n\t\t\t    Password: ";

    do
    {
        pwc=getch();
        if(pwc==13||pwc==' ')
        {
            break;
        }

        cout<<"*";
        password+=pwc;
        pw++;
    }
    while(pwc!=13||pwc!=' ');

    n=username.length();

    for(int a=0; a!=n; a++)
    {
        if(isupper(username.at(a)))
        {
        username.at(a) = tolower(username.at(a));

        }
    }



    if(username=="admin" && password=="Admin")
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout<<"\n ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"\t\t\t\t  WELCOME ADMIN!"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<" ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                Menu(username);
                return main();

        }
        else if(username=="cashier" && password=="Cashier")
        {
            system("CLS");

            cout<<"\n ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"\t\t\t\t  WELCOME CASHIER!"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<" ==============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                Menu(username);
        }
        else
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout
                <<"\n\t\t Invalid Username or Password. Please Try Again"<<endl;
                return main();
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//
//
//
//
//
void Menu(string username)
{
    head=NULL;

    int menu;
    if(username=="admin")
    {
    do
    {

    cout
        <<"\t MENU: "
        <<"\n\n\t\t\t A. FILE MAINTENANCE" <<endl
            <<"\n\t\t\t\t 1. Display All Products"<<endl
            <<"\t\t\t\t 2. Insert New Product"<<endl
            <<"\t\t\t\t 3. Delete A Product" <<endl
            <<"\t\t\t\t 4. Search A Product"<<endl
        <<"\n\t\t\t B. SALES MODULE"<<endl
            <<"\n\t\t\t\t 5. Cashier"<<endl
            <<"\t\t\t\t 6. Print Receipt."<<endl
        <<"\n\t\t\t C. EXIT"<<endl
            <<"\n\t\t\t\t 7. Log Out"<<endl;

        cout<<"\n\t Choose an option (1 to 7 only): ";
        cin>>menu;
        cin.ignore();

        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"\n ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\t\t   DISPLAY ALL PRODUCTS"<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<" ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                DisplayProduct();
                system("pause");
                system("CLS");
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"\n ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\t\t   INSERT NEW PRODUCT"<<endl;
                cout<<" ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                InsertProduct();

                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"\n ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\t\t    DELETE A PRODUCT"<<endl;
                cout<<" ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                DeleteProduct();
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"\n ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\t\t SEARCH A PRODUCT" <<endl;
                cout<<" ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                SearchProduct();
                break;
            case 5:
                cout<<"\n ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\t\t PURCHASE PRODUCTS"<<endl;
                cout<<" ============================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
                PurchaseProduct();
            case 7:
                cout<<"\n\n THANK YOU ADMIN!"<<endl<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"\n\n INVALID INPUT!"<<endl<<endl;

        }
    }while(menu!=7);
    }
    else
    {
    cout
        <<"Choose an Option"
        <<"\n1.Sales Module"
        <<"\n2.Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>menu;
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Sales Module";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Exit!";
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid Input!";

        }
    }
}

void InsertProduct()
{

    product *newproduct;
    newproduct=new product;
    cout<<"\n\n\tEnter Product Name:";getline(cin,newproduct->pname);
    cout<<"\n\tEnter Product Quantity:";cin>>newproduct->qnty;
    cout<<"\n\tEnter Product ID:";cin>>newproduct->pid;
    cout<<"\n\tEnter Product Price:";cin>>newproduct->price;
    cin.ignore();


    newproduct->ptr=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
        head=newproduct;
    else
    {
        product *lastproduct;
        lastproduct=head;
        while(lastproduct->ptr!=NULL)
            lastproduct=lastproduct->ptr;
        lastproduct->ptr=newproduct;
    }
    cout<<"\n\tProduct is inserted"<<endl;

system("pause");
system("CLS");
}

void DeleteProduct()
{
    DisplayProduct();
    product *current,*previous;
    current=head;
    int x;
    if (current==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n\t\tNo Products Found.";
    }
    else
    {

        cout<<"\n\t\tEnter Product No. to delete:";
        cin>>x;
        int i=1;
        if(x==1)
        {
            head=current->ptr;
            delete current;
            cout<<"\n\t\tProduct is deleted";
            DisplayProduct();
        }
        else
        {
            while(i<x&&current!=NULL)
            {
                previous=current;
                current=current->ptr;
                i=i++;
            }
            if(current==NULL)
            {
                cout<<"\n\t\tProduct does not Exist";
            }
            else

            {
                previous->ptr=current->ptr;
                delete current;
                cout<<"\n\t\tProduct is deleted";
                DisplayProduct();
            }

        }
    }
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
}

void DisplayProduct()
{
    product *current;
    current=head;
    int i=1;
    cout<<setiosflags(ios::left);
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n\t\t"<<setw(4)<<i;
        cout<<setw(25)<<current->pname<<setw(3)<<current->qnty <<setw(3)<<current->pid <<setw(3)<<current->price;
        current=current->ptr;
        i++;
    }

}

void SearchProduct()
{
    string sid;//Name to search
    product *current;
    current=head;
    if (current==NULL)
            cout<<"\n\t\tNo Products Found";
    else
    {
            cout<<"\n\t\tEnter product to search: ";
            cin>>sid;
            int i=1;

            while(sid.compare(current->pid))    
            {

                current=current->ptr;
                if (current==NULL)
                    break;
                i++;

            }

            if(current!=NULL)
                cout<<"\n\t\t"<<current->pid<<" is Product No."<<i;
            else
                cout<<"\n\t\t"<<sid<<" is not in the list.";
            DisplayProduct();
            cout<<endl;

    }
    system("pause");
    system ("CLS");
}   

void PurchaseProduct()
{

}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to use `main` in your program, and you're going to have problems with `std::getline` appearing to be skipped, which is easily searchable due to the multitudes of questions about it.

Comment: @Rairulyle You already know how to loop. Do it again.

Comment: I already replace the return main(); to do while now i can login to Menu again but still can't see the Data in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in memory until you save it to hardk disk, so you need to implement some mechanism for doing that.

You can choose among several options such as using data bases, plain files([XML](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language), [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml), [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), etc ...) and **object searialization** wich I think it's your best option right now. There are several libraries out there for doing that, but for start I recommend you use this [tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/serialization.htm). Then move to [A practical guide to C++ serialization](http://www.ocoudert.com/blog/2011/07/09/a-practical-guide-to-c-serialization/).

I recommend serialization because I realized you are just starting with C++. And others options like data bases and formated files(xml, Yaml, etc...) require more complex code.

Have fun!!! After you read all this stuff and (try to put it in practice), if you still can't solve your problem, come back here, and we will happy to help you.